# Combine multiple AJAX calls to one with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that retrieves PHP variables using the $get() function but I have multiple requests for each variable. I want to do this because I want the calls to be individual and not waiting to load all variables.

Here is my simple code:

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
$content1 = 'This is a good solution.';
$content2 = 'This is another good solution.';

if(preg_match('[good]', $content1)) { 

$result1 = "<p>Great, we found something here.</p>";

}else{

$result1 = "<p>Oops, nooooo.</p>";
}
/////////////////////////////////

if(preg_match('[another]', $content2)) { 

$result2 = "<p>Great, we found something here.</p>";

}else{

$result2 = "<p>Oops, nooo.</p>";
}

$action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action) {
case 'result1':
echo $result1;
break;
case 'result2':
echo $result2;
break;
default:
echo 'Test';

}
```

GET.PHP

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$.get('functions.php?action=result1', function(data) { 

$('.result1').html(data);

});


$.get('functions.php?action=result2', function(data) { 

$('.result2').html(data);

});

</script>

<div class="result1"></div>
<div class="result2"></div>
<div class="result3"></div>
<div class="result4"></div>
........
```

So how can I "combine" all javascript calls to one (using parameters, I do not know) so will not be necesary to create a call for each variable.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

$.get('functions.php?action=resultvariable', function(data) { 

$('.result_variable...').html(data);

});

</script>
```

Comment: create a variable and use document.getElementById().

Comment: How to do that, can you show me an example code?

Comment: Are you are trying to combine all of your $.get() calls? or all of your $.get() callbacks?

Comment: var idofdiv ="result1";    
var hme = document.getElementById("result1");    
hme.innerHTML = "html code here";

Comment: I am trying to combine all $.get() calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean, something like this?

```
function ajaxcall(action, div) {
    $.get('functions.php?action='+ action, function(data) { 

        $(div).html(data);

    });
}
```

You would make your calls as

```
ajaxcall('result1','.result1');
ajaxcall('result2','.result2');
ajaxcall('result3','.result3');
```

... and so on.

Comment: Something likes this :) but without using ajaxcall('result1','.result1'); I can't ??

Comment: I mean I want to call something like this ajaxcall(action, div); / should work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//PHP: put the varibles into an array

```
$variables = array('result1'=> $result1, 'result2'=> $result2);
echo json_encode($variables);
```

//JS: change the ajax call to get an json object

```
$.get('functions.php', function(data) { 

$('.result1').html(data.result1);
$('.result2').html(data.result2);


}, 'json');
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Sorry but this solution will make the calls to load all toghether not individual. I need to use my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to bind multiple async callback into one.

```
first_ajax = function(){
  return $.get("your_url.php", function(){ //blah });
}

second_ajax = function(){
  return $.get("your_second_url.php", function(){ //blah });
}

combine_two_ajax = function(){
  $.when(first_ajax(), second_ajax())
    .done( function(ret_from_first, ret_from_second){
             //something to do
             …
           }
}
```

Calling combine_two_ajax() will trigger two async and callback to you when two async tasks are all done.